# Disconnected Context was detected c# clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

> Transition into COM context 0x27a7788 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper
>   failed with the following error: Object is not connected to server
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401FD (CO_E_OBJNOTCONNECTED)). This is
>   typically because the COM context 0x27a7788 where this
>   RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy
>   doing something else and cannot process the context transition. No
>   proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component and
>   calls will be made to the COM component directly. This may cause
>   corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all
>   COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for
>   context transition, until the application is completely done with the
>   RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live
>   inside them.

I am trying to access Clipboard in my C# App....
It works .... but whenever i have following text in my clipboard it stops and give me exception Quoted above..

> else if (e == Keys)
>               {
>                   return "";
>               }

My Code is following

```
private string GetClip()
        {
            string MyStr="";
            try
            {
                if(Clipboard.ContainsText())
                MyStr = Clipboard.GetText();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return MyStr;
        }
```

Comment: It is a bug in the code that put the object on the clipboard.  The object is single-threaded and the thread that owned the object terminated without clearing the clipboard.

Comment: how i can solve this issue?? sorry i was busy in exam so i couldn't check web and reply.